# TLV431 as direct replacement of zener?

Tags: voltage-reference, batteries

The answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/117168/7685) suggests using strings of suitable zener diodes to drop the cell-voltages of a battery stack down, to measure the individual voltages by standard (that is non-high voltage) ADCs.

The setup generally:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnyYab.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For higher cells voltages the number of reference diodes increases.

My question is can I replace a string of zeners by a adjustable reference of TLV431 type for example?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZIMI8.png)</sup>

Comment: For that first circuit, wouldn't it be better to use a single 8-9 volt zener?  They've got a much sharper (I-V) corner.

Answer (score 1):

You can, provided you maintain the minimum anode current shown in the datasheet -- 80uA or 100uA, and limit the maximum voltage across the TLV431 to less than the 7V absolute maximum voltage.

Note that the current through the resistors to set the voltage is in addition to the minimum anode current.

Comment: TLV431's from LRC (Leshan Radio)(Motorola joint venture) have 18V rating which is handy. Named summat like LRV432ALT1G AFAIR.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Closer to home (for some of us) LMV431 (now also from TI) are 35V abs. max. But I bet Leshan beats TI on price by at least 20%.

Comment: In China LRV432... cost 3 to 4 cents US in 1,000 quantity. That's "fairly competitive" :-). Wow - [Digikey TO92 TL431](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TL431CZ/1026-TL431CZ-CHP/2521470) (not TLV) 5c 1k, 4c 5k. || [SOT23 6c 15k / 4.6c 150k](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TL431SDT,215/568-4883-2-ND/2122616) | [TL**V**431 14c 1k](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TLV431AFTA/TLV431AFTACT-ND/3046727) | [LMV431 16c at 25k!!!](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LMV431IM5%2FNOPB/LMV431IM5%2FNOPBTR-ND/364391)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I was cp with TI's China price. ;-)